# Need a shell script that deletes all files except *.pdf

Tags: bash, shell, sh, delete-file

Can anyone write a shell script that deletes all the files in the folder except those with `pdf` extension?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will include all subdirectories:

```
find . -type f ! -iname '*.pdf' -delete
```

This will act only in the current directory:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -iname '*.pdf' -delete
```

Comment: this will also delete the non pdf files in subdirectories

Answer (score 6):

```
$ ls -1 | grep -v '.pdf$' | xargs -I {} rm -i {}
```

Or, if you are confident:

```
$ ls -1 | grep -v '.pdf$' | xargs -I {} rm {}
```

Or, the **bulletproof** version:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -iname '*.pdf' -delete
```

Comment: ls output is meant to be displayed to the user, not parsed. ls may substitute character or reformat the filenames in order to present it to the user.

Comment: `{}` or `"{}"` makes no difference to the shell, it is a single parameter passed to the command

Comment: It is still wrong because `ls` is not meant to produce a list of files to be parsed by other tools. `ls` is meant to produce a user-readable list of files, and by making it user-readable, `ls` may substitute characters in the file names, which may cause wrong results. `touch $'A file\nwith a newline'` will create a file that will break your command.

Comment: @Juliano, agreed and upvoted your answer - but I must say, I (luckily) haven't seen a filename with a newline in it yet.

Comment: @miku `touch $'a\nfile\nwith\nnewlines\nin\nits\nname'`.

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm !(*.pdf)
```

Comment: Would be even better if you `shopt -s failglob`.

Answer (score -1):

```
ls | grep -v '.pdf$' | xargs rm
```

This will filter all files that don't end in PDF, and execute RM on them

Comment: Hmm, apparently it does. I never noticed before, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: This is terrible! **Don't use it:** parsing the output of `ls` is really bad practice and it will break in many ways (file names with spaces or that start with a hyphen).