# delete everything but files with specified extension

Tags: bash, shell

I was wondering if I can delete every file in the directory, but the ones that have specific extensions?

So, something like that will delete all but png files:

```
 find "$target" ! -name "*.png" -printf '%f\n' -delete;
```

But how would I go about deleting everything in the folder, other than *.png and, lets say, *.txt files?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need a shell script that deletes all files except \*.pdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702577/need-a-shell-script-that-deletes-all-files-except-pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` lets you use `-o` for boolean `or`:

```
find "$target" ! \( -name "*.png" -o -name "*.txt" \) -printf '%f\n' -delete;
```

Answer (score 2):

To find only pdf and txt files (to remove, replace printf with rm)

```
printf "%s\n" *.{pdf,txt}
```

To find all BUT pdf and txt files

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob
printf "%s\n" !(*.pdf|*.txt)
```

If you want to descend into subdirectories

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob globstar
printf "%s\n" **/!(*.pdf|*.txt)
```

Comment: thank you Sir, your methods work just as fine, but I accepted that other guy's response, for using find command.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider doing something like this to delete every file under $target that is not a png file:

```
find $target -name '*' | grep -v '\.(png|txt)$' | xargs rm
```